# Perl: How do I extract certain bits from a byte and then covert these bits to a hex value?

Tags: perl, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bit, text-parsing

I need to extract certain bits of a byte and covert the extract bits back to a hex value.

Example (the value of the byte is 0xD2) :

```
76543210 bit position
11010010 is 0xD2
```

- Bit 0-3 defines the *channel* which is `0010b` is `0x2`
- Bit 4-5 defines the *controller* which is `01b` is `0x1`
- Bit 6-7 defines the *port* which is `11b` is `0x3`

I somehow need to get from the byte is `0xD2` to channel is `0x2`, controller is `0x1`, port is `0x3`

I googled allot and found the functions [`pack`](http://p3rl.org/pack)/[`unpack`](http://p3rl.org/unpack), [`vec`](http://p3rl.org/vec) and [`sprintf`](http://p3rl.org/sprintf). But I'm scratching by head how to use the functions to achieve this. Any idea how to achieve this in Perl ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's the initial format?

```
my $chr = chr(0b11010010);  # A character  e.g. from read()
my $bin = '11010010';       # Binary
my $hex = 'D2';             # Hexadecimal
my $num = 0b11010010;       # A number.
my $num = 0xD2;             # A number.
```

You want to start by converting it to a number

```
my $num = ord($chr);
my $num = unpack('C', $chr);  # Alternative
my $num = oct("0b$bin");
my $num = hex($hex);
```

Then you use shifts and masks.

```
my $channel    = ($num >> 0) & 0xF;   # Or just: $num & 0xF
my $controller = ($num >> 4) & 0x3;
my $port       = ($num >> 6) & 0x3;   # Or just: $num >> 6
```

(You could use `0b1111`, `0b11` and `0b11` for the masks. Most people work in hex.)

Or let `vec` figure out the masks for you.

```
my $channel    = vec $num, 0, 4;
my $controller = vec $num, 4, 2;
my $port       = vec $num, 6, 2;
```

Here's an example for `$controller`:

```
  11010010
      >> 4
  --------
      11010010
&       11
  --------
        01
```

(Some zeroes omitted for clarity.)

Comment: Yes, the initial format is the hex value from the byte so in above example 0xD2 not what I previously indicated.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help to improve this answer. :)

Comment: After reading : http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Perl/More-Perl-Bits/
The coin dropped :-)

Answer (score 2):

[`vec`](http://p3rl.org/vec) is a good choice. I think this is pretty straightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @channels    = map "channel_$_"      => 0 .. 15;
my @controllers = map "controller_$_"   => 0 .. 3;
my @ports       = map "port_$_"         => 0 .. 3;

my $bits        = 0b11010010;
my $channel     = vec $bits, 0, 4;
my $controller  = vec $bits, 4, 2;
my $port        = vec $bits, 6, 2;

say "channel    : $channels[$channel]";
say "controller : $controllers[$controller]";
say "port       : $ports[$port]";
```

Output:

```
channel    : channel_2
controller : controller_1
port       : port_3
```